# How do I send an SMS in React Js with Twilio?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sms, twilio

So I used create-react-app to create a reactjs web app but for some reason, when I import the Twilio library/node module, I am getting this error in the browser:

```
TypeError: deprecate.stream is undefined
./node_modules/deprecate/index.js/<
node_modules/deprecate/index.js:28
```

[heres the screenshot of what I'm getting for better clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LuOg.png)

Code:

```
const _sendSMS = (num, sender, senderUID) => {
  var twilio = require('twilio');
  var client = new twilio('MY_ID_HERE', 'MY_TOKEN_HERE');
  client.messages.create({
    to: `+1${num}`,
    from: '+12169301068',
    body: `Howdy, ${sender} reccomended you to XXXXXXX!!`
  });
};
```

From what I've read online about another SMS library called nexmo, the library cannot run in a reactjs project, only on a legitimate node server. Is that the case here, am I missing some code, or configurations within the project?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If this is a project intended for learning, then by all means use twilio on the front end (that is, if you are able to. And it looks like you cannot as twilio or some dependancy of twilio might be trying to use Node libraries).

If you will be publishing this app to the world, I highly recommend that you do not use twilio on the front end. This is because you will be exposing your API credentials to the world.

What you'll want to do is send the data to your server and then use twilio on the server to send the sms.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. Spot on! The Twilio library is not built to be run in the front end and because using it like that would leak account credentials it _should not_ be used in the front end. I recommend checking out this [tutorial on sending SMS from the server in Node.js](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/node) to get started with that.